# How to create a circle and line on a graph in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, graphing

Need to create a graph in Visual Studio that graphs based on an input of `y=mx+c` or `r=(x+a)^2+(y+b)^2`.

I am fairly inexperienced in C# and need help. If it is possible through a library or however. The user needs to be able to input in the form and then next to the input it should graph the users input?

Comment: You should give it a try and post your code.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - You can get the numbers from a TextBox with TryParse.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the following with regards to posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My tags were removed sorry. I am coding in visual studio 2017 using the forms as a GUI

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should use something like [OxyPlot](http://www.oxyplot.org/) to accomplish this. There are a couple other libraries out there to accomplish this as well but this one has some pretty good [documentation](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html). Hope this helps.

Edit: I should also note this library can be used for: WPF, Windows 8, Windows Phone, Windows Phone Silverlight, Windows Forms, Silverlight, GTK#, Xwt, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Mac.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote since op literally said  `If it is possible through a library `.

Comment: Yh I wish I could upvote since it is the only solution so far but my reputation is too low :( thanks for the advise tho will definitely try out.

Comment: For sure, just glad I might have pushed you in the right direction. When you post next time please show your work / attempts. Mark this as the answer if OxyPlot ends up working for you. Good luck,